# Union of keyof keys from a type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, keyof

I have these types:

```js
type MyTableRowData = {
  id : string;
  name : string;
  total : number;
}

type TableDef<RowData> = {
  data: RowData[];
  columns: {
    [key in keyof RowData]: ColumnDef<key>;
  };
  enabledColumns: Array<string>; // I want here to be like an Array<"id" | "name" | "total">
}
```

So I can create the table:

```js
const data : MyTableRowData[] = [
  {id: "1", name: "name1", total: 0},
  {id: "2", name: "name2", total: 10},
  {id: "3", name: "name3", total: 99},
]

const table : TableDef<MyTableRowData> = {
  data: data,
  columns: {
    id: {
      //not important here, but it's a ColumnDef object
    },
    name: {
      //not important to the question...
    },
    total: {
      //not important to the question...
    },
  },
  enabledColumns: ["name", "total"] // Here I want TS to accept only "id", "name" or "total" as items in the array.
}
```

My question is:

How can I type the enabledColumn field so it can be an array that can accept only the values ("id" | "name" | "total"), like an Union?

I found many answers on transforming a keyof in Union, but not the reverse case.

The columns field works similarly to what I want, but it's an object.

---

UPDATE 1:

The problem here is that **VSCode** is not recognizing Array or (keyof RowData)[] autocomplete options when I try to use it inside the array. Also, if I put an arbitrary string there, it doesn't give me an error (only "id", "name" and "total" would be acceptable in the example).

If I do it as a manual Union (like I did in the above example), it recognizes (see screenshots below):

[image: When using keyof it does not provide the options]

[image: When using manual union type, it provides]

Comment: Add a second generic `K extends keyof T` and have `enabledColumns` be `K[]`

Comment: Have you tried `keyof RowData` instead of `string` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYK9QN)?  If not, does that work for you? If so, what's the issue?  It kind of seems like there *must* be an existing question asking for `keyof`, so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @jcalz I tried what you said, but apparently, VSCode and TS aren't recognizing it. I got the same result as the first screenshot I attached on the update of the question.

Comment: @JaredSmith I updated the question with what I got

Comment: So then is an IDE question?  On the TS Playground it works exactly as you want it to, so I think in order for this to be a [mre] you need to provide more info about the difference between those environments.  Right now it doesn't look reproducible.

Comment: @jcalz yes, I agree with you. Even my complete code is recognizable in the TS Playground you provided, but not in VSCode. IDK why :(

Answer (score 1):

The union of property names of `A` is simply `keyof A`.

```js
type MyTableRowData = {
  id : string;
  name : string;
  total : number;
}

// keyof MyTableRowData = 'id' | 'name' | 'total'

type TableDef<RowData> = {
  // ...
  enabledColumns: (keyof RowData)[];
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work. I updated the question with more information and some screenshot

Comment: Try restarting the language server. You will have to post the exact code and TypeScript version for this to be investigated further. I see your screenshot mentions `ProjectTableRowData` but the definition is not included in your question.